# Passing long to Double.parseDouble

Tags: java, numberformatexception

When I pass in a number like 100L to Double.parseDouble()
I get a NumberFormatException.
But 100L is a valid number.

EDIT: I do not get any error is if pass 100d or 100f. I only get it for 100L

Comment: sorry, in whcih language? Java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

100L is a literal that represents the long value 100. The string "100L" is not, so when you pass it to parseDouble() it rightfully complains. Drop the "L" and you should be fine.

**Update**: It's not that `parseDouble()` doesn't like the literal syntax, it's that it doesn't like that you've explicitly declared the number as being a `long` (when in fact it's looking for a floating point type.)

Comment: 100d is fine.Soo is 100f. Why is that?

Comment: As saugok wrote below, `parseDouble()` calls `valueOf()`, which is looking specifically for floating point representations. d and f denote doubles and floats, so all is well. I think my initial answer is a bit off, since the it is honouring the literal modifier, but in fact *doesn't like it*. Updating now.

Answer (score 1):

From the JavaDocs, [Double.parseDouble();](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)

> Returns a new double initialized to the value represented by the
>   specified String, as performed by the valueOf method of class Double.

Syntax,

```
public static double parseDouble(String s) throws NumberFormatException

Throws:
NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable double.
```

It expects a string to be passed as argument. "100L" is a literal having value long, not a string. To avoid any error, try using "100" instead of "100L".

> I do not get any error is if pass 100d or 100f. I only get it for 100L ?

[parseDouble()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) calls [valueOf()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29), which specifically looks for
floating point representations.Since, d and f denote doubles and floats , everything works fine.
But, you shouldn't specifiy the number explicitly as long. ( like 100L)

---

FYI,

NumberFormatException : http://www.ideone.com/DMpUN
Runs normally : http://www.ideone.com/QdxXY

---

Comment: Pretty sure he's passing in a string, though; otherwise he'd get a compilation error, rather than the runtime exception.

Comment: @dlev : Yes, of course. Otherwise he would get a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

100l in a "String" is not a valid number.  You simply need to pass in a valid double string.

```
class test{
    public static void main(String... args){
            System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("100.0000"));
    }}
```

This works fine.  As another user noted passing "100l" in the string wont work because the l implies the long value as a literal number.